# How can see the current range value (in range item) in browser in HTML with CSS and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a range item in a form but I don't know how to display the current value from the range item.

How can this be done?

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: Are you talking about specifying range in `input` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little bit of JavaScript you should be able to get your desired effect.

Simply run a function on the input change which gets the value and changes the text within an element.

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
  document.getElementById('range_value').innerHTML = val;
}

document.onload = updateTextInput('50');
```

```html
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<span id="range_value"></span>
```

Comment: Also may be useful to trigger `onchange` event manually after the page has loaded `document.getElementById("range_value").onchange();`

Comment: @n4nn31355 why would i run the `onchange()` on the span element? Probably better to run the function on page load instead...

Comment: Sorry for typo. I mean `document.getElementById("rangeInput").onchange();`